# Numpy eigh-function with proper signs

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvector

I would like to calculate the eigenvectors of a second-derivative-matrix in python. According to math the first vector should be equal to a sin-function between 0 and pi, the second equal to a sin-function between 0 and 2*pi. Thus my code looks like

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import sparse
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special
import scipy

def create_second_deriv(size, h):
    delta_matrix_2_second_diff = (np.eye(size, dtype=np.float)*-2+np.eye(size, k=-1,dtype=np.float)*1+np.eye(size, k=1,dtype=np.float)*1)
    delta_matrix_2_second_diff /= (h*h)
    return -1*delta_matrix_2_second_diff

delta_x = 0.001
x = np.linspace(0, 1, (int)(1/delta_x))
delta_matrix = create_second_deriv(len(x), delta_x)
w, v = scipy.linalg.eigh(delta_matrix)

plt.plot(v.tolist()[0])
plt.show()
plt.plot(v.tolist()[1])
plt.show()
```

Now, what I get as output, is
[image] as plot for the first eigenvector, and 
[image] as plot for the second eigenvector. I already know that the signs for the different values are arbitrary, but in my case they are important for later processing. Is there a way to "flip" the signs such that the resulting values are approximately equal to the expected functions? Simply using the `abs()`-function will not help in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a gotcha](http://www.freealf.com/2009/02/scipys-eigh-how-to-lose-an-afternoon.html) with the `scipy.linalg.eigh()` function:

> Be very careful using the `eigh()` routine to get eigenvalues, though. 
>   There's a "gotcha" buried in it.
>
> The syntax is:
>
> ```
> (eigenvalues, eigenvectors) = eigh(matrix)
> ```
>
> This returns an array of eigenvalues and a 2D array of eigenvectors
>   (each eigenvector consists of many components).
>
> And there's the gotcha.  Let's say you want the `n`th eigenvalue and
>   eigenvector.  I would write:
>
> ```
> eigenvalues[n]
> eigenvectors[n]
> ```
>
> And I would be horribly wrong.  The eigenvectors and eigenvalues do
>   share an index, but the index on the eigenvector is SECOND column:
>
> ```
> eigenvectors[:,n]
> ```

Thus, the last four lines of your code must be changed to:

```
plt.plot(v[:,0])
plt.show()
plt.plot(v[:,1])
plt.show()
```